# Disabling main window scrolling onmouseenter iframe in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, scroll

I want to disable scrolling on the main page but not within the iframe when the mouse is over it. 
You can see what I mean more clearly [here](http://jsbin.com/disable-scrolling/214/edit).

If the iframe were picking up mousewheel events then I don't want the whole page to scroll down when the mouse is inside the iframe. Note that it is working in chrome just not in ff.

Edit: The keyboard component even works as expected!

Note:

Scrolling enable/disable is based on the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/2029394)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Much simpler solution:**

Give your parent body an id (`"bodyID"` in the example), then in your enable and disable scroll functions just add:

```
function disable_scroll()
{
    document.getElementById("bodyID").style.overflow="hidden";
}

function enable_scroll()
{
    document.getElementById("bodyID").style.overflow="auto";
}
```

Basically, since you don't want the parent page to scroll, instead of targeting individual events, just disable scrolling for the parent page altogether while the cursor is inside the `iframe`. Simple, cross-browser, and much more direct.

In fact, you could eliminate 90% of your code, and just use

```
function disable_scroll()
{
    document.getElementById("bodyID").style.overflow="hidden";
}

function enable_scroll()
{
    document.getElementById("bodyID").style.overflow="auto";
}
document.getElementById("miframe").onmouseenter = disable_scroll;
document.getElementById("miframe").onmouseleave = enable_scroll;
```

you could use `document.body`, but that runs into confusion when you're playing with JSBin or the like and there's a half dozen (ok, three, but still) `documents` and `bodies`.

Check Modified JSBIN [here](http://jsbin.com/disable-scrolling/217/edit).

Comment: Nice! Didn't think of that! I'll always opt for a simpler solution. Still, I would be interested to know why the other solution doesn't work in ff.

Comment: to be honest, me too. I'm kind of curious myself.